Python under Cygwin random network failures
I'm trying to get my python project working under Cygwin on Windows 11 (coming from Macos/Linux). I'm using python 3.9.16. This is has been pretty painless except I keep getting random network failures. The weird thing is the errors don't happen outside of python.
So one thing I do is call out to ping, like this:
cp = subprocess.run(['ping', '-n', '1', hostname], capture_output = True)
return cp.returncode == 0

This will sometimes fail. Yet I can't get it to fail when I just run the command (in Cygwin's bash).
Another thing I do is resolve a hostname by simply using this standard function in the socket module:
return socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

And quite often that will just fail to find the name (with the 'Name or service not known' exception) - this can alternate between working and failing every second when I'm calling this in a loop!
This code has been well tested on macOS for ages and I've never seen anything like this.
It's driving me nuts. Anyone ever seen anything like this? This is a clean install of windows and I've turned off all the defender and firewall stuff.

Create a minimal code example that exhibits the error. Please add the check=True option to the subprocess.run call, and post the output and all error and traceback messages verbatum (for both a successful & unsuccessful run)  here or in a gist. Similarly for the socket.gethostbyname call. It would be iniformative to run these code snippits in the Windows native Python, as well as the cygwin python. You will probably find it easier to install the latest Python 3.12 as Python 3.9 is a bit out of date.
